# Remove a given entry from an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Hello everyone with a function i want to remove an entry (which i give as an argument) from an object (which i also give as an argument). To make it clearer I will provide you some code.

Here's the object I want to remove an entry from:

```
const register = {
    aap :[{condition: {aap:'aap'}, func: 'fun'}],
    aap1 :[{condition: {aap1:'aap1'}, func: 'fun'},{condition: {aap2:'aap2'}, func: 'fun'}],
};
```

The entry I want to remove looks like this : `{aap:'aap'}`

I would then invoke the function like this `myfunction(register,{aap:'aap'})`

In the above case remove  the given condition object from the register.

Now here's what i built myself :

```
const register = {
    aap :[{condition: {aap:'aap'}, func: 'fun'}],
    aap1 :[{condition: {aap1:'aap1'}, func: 'fun'},{condition: {aap2:'aap2'}, func: 'fun'}],
};



function hallo(register,condition){
    const objKeys = [];

    for(key in register){
        objKeys.push(key);
    }

    objKeys.forEach(function(el){
       console.log(register[el]);
    })

}

hallo(register);
```

I figured how to get some results which i could use to delete from  :

```
[ { condition: { aap: 'aap' }, func: 'fun' } ]
[ { condition: { aap1: 'aap1' }, func: 'fun' },
  { condition: { aap2: 'aap2' }, func: 'fun' } ]
```

But i still havent figured out how to remove the entry that matches the one i give in my function.

Long story short. I want a function that contains 2 arguments. One argument being the register (the object i would like to delete from) and the second the condition i would like to remove.

After returning the function the wanted result should be :

```
const register = {
    aap :[{condition: {}, func: 'fun'}],
    aap1 :[{condition: {aap1:'aap1'}, func: 'fun'},{condition: {aap2:'aap2'}, func: 'fun'}],
};
```

The register minus the condition i wanted removed.

Comment: `delete register.aap` ? Or `delete register["aap"];` ?

Comment: `myfunction(register,{aap:'aap'})` isn't going to be the best way to call your function since your second argument passes a unique instance of an object. Regardless of whether that object looks just like one in your target, they are not the same thing. You might be better off converting the target to a string and then passing a string to remove.

Comment: @JonasWilms I only want to remove the condition that matches the argument i pass to my function which is an object literal

Comment: What is expected output of `myfunction(register,{aap:'aap'})`?

Comment: I would like the register to be converted to this : const register = {
    aap :[{condition: {}, func: 'fun'}],
    aap1 :[{condition: {aap1:'aap1'}, func: 'fun'},{condition: {aap2:'aap2'}, func: 'fun'}],
}; @MaheerAli

Comment: Two distinct objects will never match each other - - even if all the data each holds is the same as the other.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yeah i noticed i tried checking if they were equal and even when they were it still returned false.

Comment: Right. See my first comment. You're probably better off converting your target object to a string (`JSON.stringify(obj)`) and then just doing a `string.replace()` operation.

Comment: please add a wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz added the wanted result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach by iterating all keys of the object and check if the key is in `value` and delete this key in the object.

Proceed for nested objects.

```js
function remove(object, value) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
        if (key in value && object[key] === value[key]) {
            delete object[key];
            return;
        }
        if (object[key] && typeof object[key] === 'object') {
            remove(object[key], value);
        }
    });
    return object;
}

const register = { aap: [{ condition: { aap: 'aap' }, func: 'fun' }], aap1: [{ condition:  {aap1: 'aap1' }, func: 'fun' }, { condition: { aap2: 'aap2' }, func: 'fun' }] };

console.log(remove(register, { aap: 'aap' }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```